# Jmeter assertion priority

Tags: jmeter, assertions, beanshell

Are the assertions in JMeter, executed/checked on the basis of the order of occurrence or randomly ?

I am having two (or more) assertions to all of my HTTP requests, one of them is always a response assertion checking the response code. Other one being more detailed BSF Assertion. If my response code assertion fails I don't care if the other assertion passes or fails, so I don't want it to be executed/checked.

Any suggestions for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assertions are executed upside down. So if you put BSF Assertion **under** Response Assertion and populate it as follows:

```
if (SampleResult.isSuccessful()){
    //your extended assertion logic here
}
```

extended BSF Assertion will be fired only if the following conditions are met:

- Parent sample success
- Response assertion success

If the any of condition fails only first line of the extended BSF Assertion will be executed.

For more information on using JMeter Assertions see [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide.

Comment: Yes I have been using the check in my BSF code, just that sampleResult.isSuccessful is not good enough for my case. I have to  check for response code

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are executed on basis of the order of occurrence, and currently in **Jmeter** there is **no mechanism** to **skip/ignore** any one **assertion based on the result** from previous assertion.

Probably you can combine both assertions in to BSF Assertion
where you first do a check on response code and if response code is correct/expected then do the detailed assertion.

hope this will help.

Comment: So if I have the the assertions ordered as A1, A2 ... - they will always be executed in that order. But I am surprised that we do not have any option "Not to execute further assertions" on an assertion failure kind of thing. Because that seems to be a very logical - I am interested to assert if my sampler is obedient or not - don't need to know why it failed
And yes I am having a check in my BSF script for now.  
Thanks